# My /testfor command is not working what am I doing wrong?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

[image]
I tried to use `@p`, `@e` and `@a` but it doesn’t work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use selector arguments without a selector.

```
testfor @a[name=ShapeTheCentury,x=103,y=42,z=-82,r=0]
```

Make sure there are no spaces in your selector.

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work either might be something else wrong

Comment: I am using version 1.1.5

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out, I had to get rid of the x,y,z and r they weren't registering